# How to subscribe to a notification stream for packet_In processing?

Tags: opendaylight

I am writing an external application that uses REST to communicate with open-daylight. I need to get a notification whenever a new communication between two nodes is needed.

I've checked how to subscribe for event notification in the following [link](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Restconf:Change_event_notification_subscription). But I am not sure if this is possible for a packet_in event.

Is it possible to get a notification of the new connection packet_in, with/without some information about the packet?

What would be the path used to create-data-change-event-subscription? also, how can I check all available events and paths that I can make use of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the "packet_in" event is a yang notification however the REST notification subscription mechanism is for data change notifications. Unfortunately there is no mechanism currently (that I know of) to subscribe to yang notifications over rest.

Comment: Do you know any data changes associated with a packet_in event? or should I implement an internal rpc/notification to get what I need?